# Determine the probability that each of the 8 members serves on at least one of the three committees.

Tags: probability

A certain group has 8 members. In January, 3 members are selected at random to serve on a  committee. In February, 4 members are selected at random and independently of the first selection to serve on another committee.  In March, 5 members are selected at random and independently of the previous 2 selections to serve on a third committee. Determine the probability that each of the 8 members serves on at least one of the three committees.

So I am really unsure about this problem, I put the committees choice in the denominator, to represent the total choices. My reasoning for the numerator were you can choose any 3 people from the 8, then from the remaining 5 who haven't had positions you have to choose 4 and then there is 1 left who hasn't had a position so he has to be one of the 5 selected in March, and the remaining 4 can be any from the

$\frac{{8 \choose 3}{5 \choose 4}{1 \choose 1}{7 \choose 4}}{{8 \choose 3}{8 \choose 4}{8 \choose 5}}$

So I need to use the inclusion exclusion principle?

Comment: The $4$ members in the second committee need not be members not being in the first committee.

Comment: @Peter I guess I didn't really know how else to express it so that ever member is a member is in at least one committee. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Simplify the problem.

Five members serve on the March committee and three do not.  What is the probability that there's at least one of *those three* who did not serve on either of the other two committees?  What is the complement of this?

**Hint 2:** Use the *Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion*.

Comment: I still don't really understand the principle of inclusion and exclusion fully, I just looked at the wikipedia page and got a -formula like $W={n \choose 1}(n-1)!-{n \choose 2}(n-2)!+{n \choose 3}(n-3)!$, so...maybe it's like ${3 \choose 1}(3-1)!-{3 \choose 2}(3-2)!+{3 \choose 3}(3-3)$??

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, assume that the members $1$ to $5$ belong to the third committee.

The probability that $4$ of those members belong to the second committee, is
 $\frac{\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{8}{4}}=\frac{1}{14}$. In this case, all the remaining
 members must belong to the first committee, so $\frac{1}{14}\times\frac{1}{\binom{8}{3}}=\frac{1}{784}$ is the probability in this case.

The probability that $3$ of those members belong to the second committee, is
 $\frac{\binom{5}{3} \times \binom{3}{1}} {\binom{8}{4}}=\frac{3}{7}$. In
 this case, the $2$ remaining members must belong to the first committee, so
 $\frac{3}{7}\times \frac{6}{\binom{8}{3}}=\frac{9}{196}$ is the 
 probability in this case.

The probability that $2$ of those members belong to the second committee, is
 $\frac{\binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2}} {\binom{8}{4}}=\frac{3}{7}$. In this
 case, the remaining member must belong to the first committee, so $\frac{3}{7}\times\frac{3}{8}=\frac{9}{56}$ is the probability in this case.

Finally, the probability that $1$ of those members belongs to the second committee
 is $\frac{1}{14}$. In this case, all members already belong to at least one 
 committee.

In total, the probability is $\frac{219}{784}=0.2793$

Comment: I don't understand why for the first part, "all the remaining members must belong to the first committee"?

Comment: If $4$ of the $5$ members selected in the third committee are in the second, there are $3$ members which are not yet selected.