# Determine the probability that each of the 8 members serves on at least one of the three committees

Tags: probability

A certain group has 8 members. In January, 3 members are selected at random to serve on a  committee. In February, 4 members are selected at random and independently of the first selection to serve on another committee.  In March, 5 members are selected at random and independently of the previous 2 selections to serve on a third committee. Determine the probability that each of the 8 members serves on at least one of the three committees.

Could I do something like:
Let members 1-5 be in the March group. Then I just have to find the probability that members 6,7 and 8 are not in the Jan or Feb groups.

P(committees only have members 1-5)=$\frac{{5 \choose 3}{5 \choose 4}{5 \choose 5}}{{8 \choose 3}{8 \choose 4}{8 \choose 5}}$

Then I am kind of stuck

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the sample space you got, was the total number of ways to pick committee members with no restrictions, so we divide by $\binom{8}{3}\binom{8}{4}\binom{8}{5}$.

Unfortunately, the easiest way that comes to my mind to accomplish the task of counting how many ways each member gets used at least once is via inclusion-exclusion principle.

#with all members at least once = #total - #atleastonemembernot + #atleast2membersnot - #atleast3membersnot + #atleast4membersnot - ...

$\#(\text{all members at least once})=\binom{8}{3}\binom{8}{4}\binom{8}{5} - 8\cdot\binom{7}{3}\binom{7}{4}\binom{7}{5} + \binom{8}{2}\cdot\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{4}\binom{6}{5} - \binom{8}{3}\cdot \binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{5}+0\dots$

For clarification, the third addend $\binom{8}{2}\cdot\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{4}\binom{6}{5}$ comes from first choosing which two members don't appear, then choosing which members from those remaining appear in each month's selections (it is possible that one of the remaining members happens to not be picked in any either, but that is exactly why inclusion-exclusion works!)

Thus, the final answer is:

$$\dfrac{\binom{8}{3}\binom{8}{4}\binom{8}{5} - 8\cdot\binom{7}{3}\binom{7}{4}\binom{7}{5} + \binom{8}{2}\cdot\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{4}\binom{6}{5} - \binom{8}{3}\cdot \binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{5}}{\binom{8}{3}\binom{8}{4}\binom{8}{5}}$$